# Wordpress - Filtered function

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I write a WordPress custom function that will fire on particular post categories?

Apply this

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'Pub Top Single Post All' )
```

On blog category `X`, `Y`, `Z` only

Answer (score 0):

Why not embed this sidebar inside the template itself?

```
<?php if (in_category('baked-goods')) || is_category( 'baked-goods' )): ?>
    dynamic_sidebar( 'Pub Top Single Post All' )
<?php endif ?>
```